# How to implement my custom development multiple PHP page work into Wordpress?

Tags: templates

I have developed a custom PHP page with filters, add to cart module, music playlist everything. How can i implement it into WordPress? I am a newbie, any help thanks.

My custom PHP work directory structure :

```
location    : public_html/my_work

website URL : website.com/my_work
```

Everything is working good, but my WordPress Header and Footer are missing. How to implement my custom development multiple PHP page work into WordPress?

Comment: Any help to improve my question?

Comment: you could improve your  question by explaining how those diverse customizations tie together and how you want it to interact with WordPress. have you looked into using a shortcode or a template to display your custom page?

Comment: ps. I upvoted your question for actually asking how to improve it, which no one ever seems to do and why I responded. :-)

Comment: @majick I really appreciated your work.

Comment: Pls check with my updated post.

Comment: there are a few different ways you can do this, it depends how much content you have and what the desired structure of it is. if it's a one-off thing, use a *shortcode*. if it's content with changes depending on different page, consider using a *page template*. yet another alternative is use *the_content* to insert your content in an existing theme template for a page/post.

Comment: @majick Yes, content with changes depending on different pages.

Comment: Adding your existing file list/structure to your question would help clear this up, because that could still mean lots of complely different pages (different document), or lots of content (with the same document structure) or some mix of the two.

Comment: website.com is your WordPress setup? and what is this website.com/my_work Do you have my_work directory that contains your own php files?

Comment: @Vantiya Yes, website.com/my_work contains my PHP work contains css,js,html,php,phtml. How can i integrate with wordpress.

Comment: So you're saying those files are working ok just not working header and footer functions of wordpress i.e. get_header() and get_footer(). is it so?

Comment: @Vantiya Exactly, now my project look like : https://snipboard.io/2sWyGg.jpg  how to add wordpress header and footer?

Comment: from URL voicebank is my project folder, my project contains multiple PHP page, html, css, css see https://www.webslesson.info/2018/08/how-to-make-product-filter-in-php-using-ajax.html

Comment: You need to add a line of code on each files (or based on your structure if all files are loaded from one single index.php file you need to include on that page) 

** require ('../wp-blog-header.php'); **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99868/discussion-between-gem-and-vantiya).

Comment: @Gem I'm going to add the solution here. please accept it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can integrate your PHP file into WordPress with various ways like you can create a plugins and activate plugins and then you get all your PHP file accessible to WP functions.

It's bit dirty but in your case if you wish you add `require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');` on top of the files or if all files are loaded through index.php add the code on top of the file and after that you can include `get_header()` and in footer you can write `get_footer()`.

In response to your question in chat for not accessing this in local host is, localhost $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns path to localhost/ and your package is accessible on localhost using http://locahost/yoursite You have to modify for localhost or if you test this on server with subdomain you have to modify code like `require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/yoursite/wp-load.php');`

Comment: WordPress has its own constants and functions to get directories like `get_template_directory()` I would not recommend using any `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and general PHP stuff like that but rather work with what WP offers.

Comment: @NextGenThemes Thanks for your update and DOWN VOTE but can you tell me until WP accessible in custom PHP file how could any one write get_template_directory() function without getting an error undefined function?

Comment: NO problem, you of course are supposed to fully load WordPress first. But you both seem not to be up for what is best but rather what works first. You should be happy he accepted your bad answer. You are supposed to use `get_header()` inside a theme and when you are loading a theme correctly you have access to all the WP functions (excluding only admin code). I am not sure what you are doing but its wrong, and pretty much proves my point that you should not start with using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and the likes at all when using WP.

Answer (score 2):

Abandon your old structure! Possibly move it into a plugin. You are entering a new and complicated world and it looks like you need to learn about it. Better learn how WP works instead of trying to make it bend to what you have in mind.

If you want dynamic things happening from existing php code the simplest way to get that into WP are shortcodes. You make your code `return` what you want to output on a page/post and then put that shortcode in where your php generated stuff should be.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: BestPluginEva
Plugin URI:
Description:
Version: 0.0.1
Author: You
Author URI:
License: GPLv3
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/ 
namespace You\YourStuff;

add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\register_shortcode' ); 

function register_shortcode() {
    add_shortcode( 'old_content_output', __NAMESPACE__ . '\old_content_shortcode' );
}

function old_content_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null ) {

    $shortcode_html_output = your_old_content();

    // always return never echo or break out of php into HTML
    return $shortcode_html_output;
}
```

This can get your started. Then put `[old_content_output]` into a page to get your old php code to output it there.

Comment: My application like => https://www.webslesson.info/2018/08/how-to-make-product-filter-in-php-using-ajax.html, more than one PHP page, index.php is the main file, how can i proceed with your guide?

Comment: If pages are loaded with AJAX but switch by a #url-hash you could still make it work in a single WordPress page. But again: I feel you are going to fast and possibly doing it wrong. You can not just move something like that into WP. You need to learn how WP actually works and probably completely redo that you got. For example that tut uses `mysql` and `jquery`. WordPress has its own API for MySql that you need to learn how to use and create tables in a secure way. Then you need to use the jQuery version that WP comes with and learn how the `wp_enqueue` system works ...

Comment: What you are asking for can not just simply answered with a one and only working solution. There is also the `WP REST API` that you would ideally use to make AJAX requests for data stored in the WP mysql database ...

Comment: Successfully integrated header & footer. code :  require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');
and using get_header(); & get_footer(); now everything alright.